# DirectX Camera Jitter

Tags: matrix, camera, directx

[Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mtw15fz1igedf0/Graphics-II.rar?dl=0).

I'm making a small DirectX Demo Scene but my camera seems to "snap" to odd positions when I attempt to rotate it. It only happens when rotating and I can't seem to find out what is causing it.

```
// Get the cursor pos and calculate change in movement
POINT cursorPos;
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
LONG deltaX = oldCursorPos.x - cursorPos.x;
LONG deltaY = oldCursorPos.y - cursorPos.y;

// Hold right click to rotate
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))
{
    XMMATRIX xRotation = XMMatrixRotationY(((float)-deltaX  * (float)timer.Delta()));
    XMMATRIX yRotation = XMMatrixRotationX(((float)-deltaY * (float)timer.Delta()));

    XMMATRIX view = XMLoadFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix);

    XMFLOAT4 viewVector = XMFLOAT4(cameraMatrix.m[3][0], cameraMatrix.m[3][1], cameraMatrix.m[3][2], 1.0f);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) { cameraMatrix.m[3][i] = 0.0f; }

    view = view * xRotation;
    view = yRotation * view;

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix, view);

    cameraMatrix.m[3][0] = viewVector.x;
    cameraMatrix.m[3][1] = viewVector.y;
    cameraMatrix.m[3][2] = viewVector.z;
}

oldCursorPos = cursorPos;
```

Above is the code that performs the rotations to the camera matrix, below is the code I use to set the view matrix equal to the inverse of the camera matrix. Both of these operations are done every frame.

```
XMMATRIX camera = XMLoadFloat4x4(&cameraMatrix);
XMMATRIX view = XMMatrixInverse(NULL, camera);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&sceneMatrix.viewMatrix, view);
```

Both of these snippets don't seem to be the problem though, as I have triple checked my notes and this is exactly how my instructor expects it to be done. This bug happens in debug and release mode.

I put the source code in the link above if an attractive person such as yourself dare look at the rest of the code. Beware: It is a small demo application so try not to cringe at the hard-coded objects and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain it's causing your problem, as a simple demo might have a consistent frame-rate, but you shouldn't be scaling mouse movement by a time delta.

These lines:

```
XMMATRIX xRotation = XMMatrixRotationY(((float)-deltaX  * (float)timer.Delta()));
XMMATRIX yRotation = XMMatrixRotationX(((float)-deltaY * (float)timer.Delta()));
```

Should be

```
float fRotationSpeed = 0.01f;  // Tweak this.
XMMATRIX xRotation = XMMatrixRotationY(((float)-deltaX  * fRotationSpeed));
XMMATRIX yRotation = XMMatrixRotationX(((float)-deltaY * fRotationSpeed));
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. In my head using time.delta() made sense, because I wanted to track the change in mouse movement along with how fast that change occurred. But the amount of change per frame already accomplishes this. I appreciate the help :)